# How to model a subset of a discriminated union in F#?

Tags: f#, data-modeling

I want a thing (person, object, whatever) to have abilities (jump, run, etc.). I want some things to only have certain abilities. These are my current types:

```
type Ability =
  | Jump
  | Stay
  | Run
  | Walk

type Person = {
  abilities : Ability Set // OK, since a person should be able to do all of the above
}

type InanimateObject = {
  abilities : Ability Set // Not OK, it should only be able to "Stay"
}

type ThingWithAbilities =
  | Person of Person
  | InanimateObject of InanimateObject
```

I want a caller of my API to be able to ask for a `ThingWithAbilities` with a specific ability. Example: *Give me all objects of `ThingWithAbilities` that has the ability "Jump"*. How can I model this in a good way? I want to make it impossible to create an `InanimateObject` with the ability "jump" in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do this in a type-safe way, then you'll need to define different types for different sets of abilities:

```
type InanimateAbility =
  | Stay

type AnimateAbility = 
  | Jump
  | Run
  | Walk

type Ability = 
  | Inanimate of InanimateAbility
  | Animate of AnimateAbility

type Person = {
  abilities : Ability Set
}

type InanimateObject = {
  abilities : InanimateAbility Set
}
```

Here, `InanimateAbility` is a type for abilities that only inanimate objects have and `AnimateAbility` is a type for abilities that are unique to animate objects. `Ability` combines both of these and represents any kind of ability. `Person` can then have a set of `Abilitiy` values, but you can restrict abilities of `InanimateObject` to a set of `InanimateAbility` values.

This works fine as long as you do not have too many combinations - if you had four different kinds of objects with various subsets of abilities, then it might get messy. In that case, you would probably just use one type with a runtime check to make sure that you only assign allowed abilities to each object.

Answer (score 3):

you could model them seperately and then define your Person/Object types with reference to the atomic abilities

```
type Jump = Jump
type Stay = Stay
type Run = Run
type Walk = Walk

type Person = {
  abilities : Choice<Jump,Stay,Run,Walk> Set
}

type InanimateObject  = {
  abilities : Stay Set // actually haveing this as a set is a bit odd...but whatever
}

type ThingWithAbilities =
    | Person of Person
    | InanimateObject of InanimateObject
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Here `type Jump = Jump` is a complex object, where the name `Jump` refers to a DU and also refers to the only case of this DU. This can be simplified to `type Jump = class end`.

Comment: I think the construction is quite normal in Haskell